# How to set home route in json-server

Tags: reactjs, json-server

How can I set home route in json-server to be `"/api"` instead of `"/"`?
I tried this:

```
server.use(jsonServer.rewriter({
  "/api/": "/"
}));
```

but, it does not work

Comment: Did you try with `"/api/*": "/$1"` ?

Comment: I put as answer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `"/api/*": "/$1"` you should match the route `/`.

See https://github.com/typicode/json-server#add-custom-routes.